# CSS font property tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The tag [font-bold](/questions/tagged/font-bold) has more questions tagged to it, than its competitor [font-weight](/questions/tagged/font-weight). While there is no mention of [font-bold](/questions/tagged/font-bold) property on the [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html) docs; I think these both should be merged, and `font-weight` should replace the older `font-bold` tag completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`font-weight` is a CSS property while "font bold" seems to be a way of saying "this question is about the use of bold in a font". Many of the questions tagged [font-bold](/questions/tagged/font-bold) are decidedly *not* about CSS either, so I don't think the two tags are competing in any way.

The excerpt that you originally gave to the [font-weight](/questions/tagged/font-weight) tag doesn't make sense either:

> The font-weight property selects the weight of the font. Tag to be used with CSS property font-weight or font-bold.

There is no such CSS property as `font-bold`.

That said, neither tag seems overly useful (and [font-bold](/questions/tagged/font-bold) doesn't seem legitimately useful as a proper tag *at all*). I (well, Wesley and I) decided to remove them both instead. [fonts](/questions/tagged/fonts) is enough in most cases.

Comment: I think we're stepping on eachother's toes with edits, I was removing `font-weight` from the two questions. I don't think we need either one, especially with total 16 questions. Thoughts? If you agree I will remove them all myself.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: 30 questions total actually - I had just removed [font-bold] from a handful of them. *Personally* I don't like [font-size] either and would very much rather have neither [font-size], [font-weight] nor any of the other specific CSS font properties, nor [font-bold], and just have [fonts]. Considering the low use of these specific tags, though, I suppose there's no harm in doing away with them for now.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and retag/untag then, if the tag hasn't picked up steam by now it never will, might as well nip it in the bud.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Cool, thanks for your help!

Comment: They're gone, `[status-completed]`.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: More like declined, since the OP is asking to make them synonyms whereas we got rid of them entirely.

Comment: They're both merged into the trash can.